# error with input array type in argument 6 of stereoRectify()

Tags: c++, opencv, point-cloud-library, ros

I need to compute a point cloud from stereo images after computing their disparity map. 
Please find the code at http://goo.gl/enM7i1

```
Mat R1, R2, Q
Eigen::Quaterniond q;
Eigen::Vector3d t;
Eigen::Matrix3d mR = q.matrix();
stereoRectify(left_K,left_D,right_K,right_D,disp.size(),mR,t,R1,R2,left_P,right_P,Q); }
```

I am getting this error while compiling:

```
    invalid initialization of reference of type ‘cv::InputArray {aka const cv::_InputArray&}’ from expression of type ‘Eigen::Matrix3d {aka Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>}’   stereoRectify(left_K,left_D,right_K,right_D,disp.size(),mR,t,R1,R2,left_P,right_P,Q);
                                                                                  ^
```

Thanks

Comment: The compiler tells you what the type is, and what it really expects. Now you have to think about how to convert (not cast!) your type to the expected. Or read a reference to see if you actually are passing the correct arguments

Comment: Could you help me with conversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got this after hours of researching. The error was due to invalid passing of Eigen type input in 6th 7th argument.

The soln is conversion between Eigen type matrix to cv::Mat type expected argument(inputArray)

```
Mat R1, R2, Q;
Eigen::Quaterniond q = rots[0];
Eigen::Vector3d t = trans[0];
std::cout << q.matrix() << std::endl;
std::cout << t << std::endl;
// Converting Eigen type to Opencv type inputArray ---> Mat

Eigen::Matrix3d mR = q.matrix();
cv::Mat mr2 = cv::Mat::eye(3,3, CV_64F);
eigen2cv(mR, mr2);
cv::Mat T = cv::Mat::zeros(3,1,CV_64F);

T.at<double>(0,0) =   t(0,0);
T.at<double>(0,1) =   t(1,0);
T.at<double>(0,2) =   t(2,0);
```